# Topological Continuous Functions

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y$ be an ordered set in the order topology. Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be continuous.

(a) Show that the set $\{x\mid f(x)\le g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

(b) Let $h:X\to Y$ be the function $h(x)=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$. Show that $h$ is continuous. [Hint: Use the pasting lemma.]

Looking for reasons as to why this proof fails, or is not entirely complete.

Let $v=\{f(x)\mid f(x)\leq g(x)\}$, then $Y-v=\{f(x)\mid f(x)>g(x)\}$ which is an open set in $Y$, thus $v$ is a closed set in $Y$. By Thm 18.1 (see bottom) $f^{-1}(v)=u$ where $u=\{x\mid f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ and thus is a closed set.

Thm 18.1: a continous function takes closed sets to closed set.

Comment: This was just a solution to part a

Comment: (1) Are you sure you stated the theorem correctly? (2) Since $v$, as you defined it, is a subset of $X$, not of $Y$, setting up "$Y-v$" makes no sense. So the rest of the "proof" doesn't matter...

Comment: Your correct, I have redid the notation in my proof

Comment: A continuosu function does not take closed sets to closed sets: the inverse of a closed set is closed.

Comment: It's not clear why $\{f(x) ; f(x) > g(x)\}$ would be open in $Y$. This requires an argument, if it's at all true. Where do you use continuity of $f$ and $g$ *exactly* and the fact that $Y$ is ordered etc.?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have sense reworked my proof incorporating these ideas and it seems to work better then before.

Answer (score 5):

(b) follows from the pasting lemma as soon as we have shown (a):

Let $A = \{x: f(x) \le g(x)\}$, $B = \{x: g(x) \le f(x)\}$. They are both closed by two applications of a). Also $h | A = f$ by definition and $h | B = g$ and so on both sets $h$ restricted is continuous. As we have a linear order, for any $x$, we always have $f(x) \le g(x)$ or $g(x) \le f(x)$ (or both when $f(x)= g(x)$). So $A \cup B = X$. The pasting lemma for finitely many closed sets now says that $h$ is continuous on $X$.

(a) would follow from the following lemma:

If $Y$ is an ordered topological space, $L = \{(y,y') \in Y^2: y \le y'\}$ is closed in $Y^2$.

Assuming this lemma, (a) follows from standard facts on the product topology:

The function $f \nabla g: X \rightarrow Y \times Y$ defined by $(f \nabla g)(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ is continuous (as the compositions $\pi_1 \circ (f \nabla g) = f, \pi_2 \circ (f \nabla g) = g$ are both continuous). And by definition:

$$\{x: f(x) \le g(x)\} = (f \nabla g)^{-1}[L]$$

and the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed.

Now prove the lemma from the definition of the product topology and the ordered topology.

Comment: In order to use the pasting lemma, we need the functions f and g to have domain A and B. In this case are you restricting f to have the domain B and g to have the domain A?,Then we would need to justify why these new functions are continuous.

(pasting lemma: https://i.imgur.com/r43ym2K.png), and then would using this fact (https://i.imgur.com/y35YXE7.png) be what we need to complete the proof? (screenshots from munkres)

Comment: @cuppajoeman $h$ is defined on all of $X$. On $A$ the restriction of $h$ is just $$ restricted to $A$ and $f$ is *given* to be continuous and so is restriction to $A$ is too. For $B$ the same argument but using the continuous $g$ instead. So the pasting lemma applies.